# Valores do position absolute funcionar para chrome e firefox?

Tags: css

Olá estou com um problema, meu elemento não esta respeitando as posições no firefox igual respeita no chrome, por exemplo, coloco position absolute, com right: -160px, blz n ochrome atinge a posição que quero, porem no firefox preciso colocar uns -180px; para respeitar.

Existe algum meio de se fazer o elemento atingir a mesma posição nos dois navegadores colocando o mesmo valor?

```css
.like{
      display: flex;
      -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      position: absolute;
      right: -160px;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%);
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 4px;
      overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Achei que pudesse ser o display: flex, mas alterei para block e continuou na mesma.

Não testei em outros navegadores.

**UPDATE:**

[Exemplo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yzpRyK)

Comment: já fez um teste sem o ponto na frente do like -> like { ...}

Comment: É preciso postar mais código HTML/CSS para que possamos reproduzir o problema, pois esse problema pode estar dependendo muito do contexto, e só com esse código informado na pergunta fica complicado. Criei uma situação hipotética aqui usando esse CSS informado e em todos os navegadores a posição do `.like` foi a mesma.

Comment: Veja: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8sT7.jpg

Comment: @Dvdsamm cara fiz um exemplo e atualizei la.

Comment: Ué, aqui apareceu na mesma posição nos 2 navegadores: https://i.stack.imgur.com/npWLZ.jpg

Comment: @Dvdsamm  poutz sera que é problema aqui então, bom vou tentar mais por aqui... Obrigado.